# Is it possible to use base maps while authorizing via ArcGIS tokens?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, basemap, token

I'm using [IdentityManager](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-identity-IdentityManager.html) to access secured resources (using ArcGIS tokens). There were no issues while I was using portal items like this:

```
const webMap = new WebMap({
  portalItem: {
    id: 'some-portal-id'
  }
});
```

But recently I tried to add base maps and the requests were ending up with 401:

```
const webMap = new WebMap({
  basemap: {
    style: {
      language: 'nl',
      id: 'arcgis/dark-gray',
      serviceUrl: `https://basemapstyles-api.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/styles/v2/styles`
    }
  }
});
```

[image: Request ended up in 401 due to token absence]

If I add that token (ArcGIS token from IdentityManager) manually to the URL there are no issues

[image: The same request, but with a token]

Is there a way to specify a token when creating a basemap instance? Or make it use IdentityManager anyhow?

The package I'm using is **"@arcgis/core": "^4.28.10"**

Answer (score 1):

You can use `esriConfig.apiKey` for authentication (see https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-config.html#apiKey).

Here is an example of how it is used:

```
require([
    "esri/config",
    "esri/Map",
    "esri/views/MapView",
    "esri/widgets/ScaleBar",
    "esri/widgets/Sketch",
    "esri/Graphic",
    "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer",
    "esri/geometry/geometryEngine",
    "esri/Basemap",
    "esri/core/reactiveUtils"
], (esriConfig, Map, MapView, ScaleBar, Sketch, Graphic, GraphicsLayer, geometryEngine, Basemap, reactiveUtils) => {
    esriConfig.apiKey = "AAPKe1c05b9485c44780824e587fe012a020tUuqQMozRdQZiJa_DA9xrDKX6I5Dsl7F9KurI89k2tGEKbfrfdpoX6ek8Kh0rqIf";



    const graphicsLayer = new GraphicsLayer();

    const map = new Map({
        basemap: new Basemap({
            portalItem: {
                id: "979c6cc89af9449cbeb5342a439c6a76"  // Light Gray Canvas
            }
        }),
        layers: [graphicsLayer]
    });

    const view = new MapView({
        container: "viewDiv",
        map: map,
        center: [-75.056, 38.540], // Longitude, latitude
        zoom: 5 // Zoom level
    });

    var currZoom = null;
    
    const handle = reactiveUtils.watch(
      () => [view.stationary, view.zoom],
      ([stationary, zoom]) => {
        if(stationary && (zoom != currZoom)){
          currZoom = zoom;
          console.log(`Change in zoom level: ${zoom}`);
        }
       }
    );

    const sketch = new Sketch({
        layer: graphicsLayer,
        view: view,
        // graphic will be selected as soon as it is created
        creationMode: "update",
        availableCreateTools: ["polygon", "rectangle"],
        updateOnGraphicClick: true,
        visibleElements: {
            createTools: {
                point: false,
                circle: false
            },
            selectionTools: {
                "lasso-selection": false,
                "rectangle-selection": false,
            },
            settingsMenu: false,
            undoRedoMenu: false
        }
    });
    sketch.on(["update"], onGraphicUpdate);
    
    function onGraphicUpdate(evt) {
      var feature = Terraformer.ArcGIS.parse(evt.graphics[0]);
      var wkt = Terraformer.WKT.convert(feature.geometry);
      console.log(wkt);
    }

    view.ui.add(sketch, "top-right");

    const scalebar = new ScaleBar({
        view: view,
        unit: "metric"
    });
    view.ui.add(scalebar, "bottom-right");

    const measurements = document.getElementById("measurements");
    view.ui.add(measurements, "manual");
});
```

Comment: Thanks @TomazicM, I'm aware that it's possible to use API key to achieve it, but it's a hard requirement to use ArcGIS token. For now, I'm using a webmap that contains a basemap I want to use. I just wanted to know if it's possible to skip that webmap as a mediator

Comment: I'm not some ArcGIS expert, so I can't help you any further.